# How can I replace the contents of an element using PHP::DOMDocument?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a lot of data in the `head` of my document, but I want to add more data. So how can I replace the contents of the `<head>` tag using [PHP::DOMDocument](http://php.net/dom)?

I have the following code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
@$dom->loadHTML($page);

$head = $dom->getElementsByTagName('head');

$keywords = new DOMElement('meta');
keywords->setAttribute('name', 'keywords');
$keywords->setAttribute('content', $page_def['keywords']);
$head->appendChild($keywords);

$description = new DOMElement('meta');
$description->setAttribute('name', 'description');
$description->setAttribute('content', $page_def['description']);
$head->appendChild($description);

$page = $dom->saveHTML();

page::dump($page);return;
```

But I get an error: Call to undefined method DOMText::setAttribute()

**EDIT:**
I wound up seeing that it is very difficult to use PHP:DOMDocument for this. In that case, I used the following code:

```
// Add the small meta data set to the header
$page = utility::replaceStringBetween('<head>', '</head>', $header . $headers, $page);
if (utility::getReplacementCount() == 0)
{
    $error = "During page write: The head tags could not be modified within your page";
    if (settings::getConfig('context') == 'production')
    {
        if (settings::getConfig('log_enabled') == 'true')
        {
            dblog::insert(user::getId(), $error, 'error');
        }
    }
    // So the live pages will display correctly, unset the merge mode since the process which unsets it will fail to execute
    if (isset($_SESSION['merge_mode'])) unset($_SESSION['merge_mode']);

    print $error;
    return;
}

/**
* Replace the value between two other values in a string
* 
* @param string start delimeter
* @param string end delimeter
* @param string replacement
* @param string original source
* @param int limit replacement count
* @return string
*/
public static function replaceStringBetween($start, $end, $new, $source, $limit = 1)
{
    $result = preg_replace('#('.preg_quote($start) . ')(.*)('.preg_quote($end) 
        . ')#is', '$1' . $new . '$3', $source, $limit, $count);

    if ($count > 0)
    {
        self::$replacement_count++;
        return $result;
    }
    $result = preg_replace ("#{$start}(.*){$end}#is", $new, $source, $limit, $count);
    if ($count > 0)
    {
        self::$replacement_count++;
        return $result;
    }
    return $source;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAttribute()` doesn't work on `DOMText` nodes.

try this:

```
$keywords = $dom->createElement('meta');
```

Comment: I tried createElement but it doesn't support modification: No Modification Allowed Error

Comment: `$dom->createElement()` works just fine for me.. I only get the error if I use `new DOMElement()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [GetElementsByTagName](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) to find the `<head>` tag and then [appendChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) to add more . . . stuff.

Alternately you could edit the `DOMNode->$nodeValue`.

Comment: I am getting an error. I have documented it in my question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Noor Try using `createElement` instead of `createTextNode`

Comment: I tried createElement but it doesn't support modification: No Modification Allowed Error

Answer (score 0):

> But I get an error: Call to undefined
>   method DOMText::setAttribute()

That is because there is no method `setAttribute` in the [DOMText](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) class. There is one in [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php).

Comment: I updated my code above but I am getting this error:
No Modification Allowed Error using setAttribute.